# Fetch missing numbers from receipt book based on range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to print missing receipt numbers from receipt book (i.e which I have not used).

I have table called receipt_book where i can define receipt number range (i.e start and end number) like 1 to 100. And i will insert receipt number based on the range. Now i want a MySQL query to get a list of numbers which numbers i didn't use. For Example:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------------+
| receipt_book_id | start_number | end_number |
+-----------------+--------------+------------+
|               1 |            1 |         5  |
+-----------------+--------------+------------+

+----------------+--------------+
| user_id        |receipt_number|
+----------------+--------------+
|               1|            1 | 
|               2|            3 | 
+----------------+--------------+
```

from above table i have used receipt number 1, 3

I want below expected result

```
+----------------------+
| NotUsedReceiptNumber |
+----------------------+
|                   2  | 
|                   4  | 
|                   5  | 
+----------------------+
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: Which dabase are you using? (MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL ...)

Comment: i am using MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a table containing all possible receipt numbers (1, 2, ..., 100) and join with it:

```sql
SELECT receipt_numbers.receipt_number
FROM       receipt_book
INNER JOIN receipt_numbers ON receipt_numbers.receipt_number BETWEEN receipt_book.start_number AND receipt_book.end_number
LEFT  JOIN receipt_used    ON receipt_numbers.receipt_number = receipt_used.receipt_number
WHERE receipt_used.receipt_number IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. can we get the same output without using 3rd table?

Comment: No. There has to be something to generate missing data. If you're using MySQL 8 then you can use recursive queries but I do not recommend that.